# Duplicating Complete Wordpress Install for Development and then Redeployment?

Tags: database, duplicates

What is the best way to duplicate an entire Wordpress site, including database, themes, plugins and all associated settings to another URL for development purposes, and then redeploying it back to the main site?

The site in question is a large Wordpress install — Wordpress 3.5 to be specific — with thousands of posts and a large audience.

I have seen various plugins which purport to do this, but what is the best way to duplicate for development and then, in a month or two, redeploy back? I am committed to keeping the development database up to date manually with the existing database once the split occurs – I don't envision using the same database on two installs or whatever.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to create a subdomain on your host?

Comment: Yes, our host is Amazon AWS.

Comment: Sorry it took so long....There's a lot of info below.  If you have any questions please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment I work in has a development, staging and production server. We set up a Git repository and don't track the wp-config file. We always copy the DB down, production -> staging -> development, and not the other way around.

Only thing you have to do when you pull commits after your create plugins, update plugins or modify URL stuff is activate, deactivate/reactivate and flush the permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

The method I use on Live domains is:

1. Create a subdomain using your host's control panel named developer/test etc.
   Ex: developer.example.com
2. Login to your site via FTP, and copy your entire root to your machine, i.e if your root is public_html, highlight it in your FTP software, and download to desktop.
3. In the copy on your desktop, rename wp-config.php to wp-config.old
4. Copy public_html from the location you saved it to in Step 2 to the new directory that should have been created at the end of Step 1.
5. Choose a database Option from below. Use your preferred method and your hosting tools to copy the data.  The question you asked is answered with option 1.
6. Upload the wp-config.old file you modified in step 5 to the sub domain.  Rename it to wp-config.php
7. Type the subdomain in your browser.  You should see a copy of your production site, but we aren't done yet.
8. Login as your admin user.  Modify the admin password in the developer instance only.  This helps you remember which site you're working on.
9. Activate a robots.txt File to keep Search engines from indexing the subdomain.  See [Block a Subdomain from Search Engines](http://moz.com/community/q/block-an-entire-subdomain-with-robots-txt)

---

### Database Option 1

Make a copy of your Database from your host control panel, i.e highlight the current database, and find the button that says Copy Database.  When it asks for a new name, name it the original name and add _dev to the end.  In wp-config.old find the dabase connection info, and change the table information to match your new *_dev database.  Copy the wp_* tables into the *_dev database. See this [answer over at StackOverFlow - Production DB to Dev DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754607/i-want-to-copy-table-contained-from-one-database-and-insert-onto-another-databas).  If you want to merge changes when finished, use the Link for Option 1 to copy *_dev into Production

### Database Option 2

If your host doesn't allow multiple databases, in wp-config.old find the line #table_prefix.  Change the table prefix to something like devwp_.  Copy the wp_* tables into the new wpdev_* tables.  See [this answer over at StackOverFlow - Production Tables to Dev Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343644/in-mysql-how-to-copy-the-content-of-one-table-to-another-table-within-the-same).  If you want to merge changes when finished, use the Link for Option 2 to copy wpdev_* into Production

Comment: That is absolutely fantastic. Thank you so much. However, I haven't grasped the final part, wherein the database table is copied back into the original database. Won't there be duplicate posts, then?

Comment: Actually, I have just thought of what I think would work, if I plan to update the second site as the main site is being updated: it would simply be a matter of copying the public_html from the subdomain over to the main domain, while leaving the same database and deleting the subdomain install, right?

Comment: Use the link in either option to go back and forth, from dev to production and vice versa.  To control the amount of duplication you are going to have to run a compare.  Export the data before a merge into Excel etc from both databases and then do an insert 1 by one.  Please note you can't use the WordPress UI for that.  Add a plugin like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/) to Production while performing `INSERT's` and `UPDATE's`

Comment: You never want to delete the subdomain.  That's why Step 9 exists.  You'll always have "a rolling development environment" as long as you follow this method.  If your development cycles are extended periods, i.e. fix something then wait a year then its easier to empty the subdomain and repeat these steps a year later.  I think that's where you were headed.

Comment: @EdmundHeaphy Welcome to Stack Exchange BTW

Comment: @ E Carter Young Thanks! One last question: if I want to prevent any issues of duplicates or having to deal with merging completely, could I just duplicate the subdomain database as in 'Option 1' again, and change the references in the live wp-config (provided I have copied the entire public_html from the subdomain over)? Merging doesn't seem logical when it will be replacement of an entire database with the new one.

Comment: @EdmundHeaphy You miss the Idea.  Say you complete all these steps and start updating.  Since the dev site is hidden, I come to your prroduction site and add a comment to Post XYZ.  In your dev database, you only have Post XYZ, but no comment.  For continuity, how are you going to add my comment if you make the dev database the production database as you propose??  In short, you'll lose all updates between the time you started updating and the time you replace databases.  That's bad form because I can come complain to you that my valid comment disappeared.

Comment: @EdmundHeaphy While reading Other Posts here, I found [this plugin](http://lifeinthegrid.com/labs/duplicator/), if you prefer the somewhat automated route.

Comment: OK, I understand the problem. The issue is that I've done a lot of similar things to this (and have significant WP experience), but can't exactly grasp that _one_ final step when I want to move stuff from the dev site to the production site. Like where is that stuff regarding `CREATE` and `INSERT` even inputted? And what exactly am I doing regarding conflicts between databases? Apologies for seeming feckless with this.

Comment: I apologize your reps not high enough to chat yet.  See Update, but before I type the update, is AWS [Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/) or [cPanel](http://cpanel.net/) Based?

Comment: AWS is neither. You have to access it through SSH. Thanks for all your help – but I think I've come around to working off a git repository, which is another whole load of stuff to get my head around!

Comment: Are you  sure?? For you to have a Working Setup, each Git Revision is going to require a WordPress install

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Git is a micro management system designed to track small changes - and big ones, to a set of files etc, which means that for every change you make the branch generates a new set, which will generate a new wordpress, so I ask, what is your goal in this endeavor? As Kel points out below, you must use Git in the model he describes.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes – that is the plan. I mean I have decided that a git workflow like he describes makes much more sense than the type of workflow I was envisaging when I asked this question.

Comment: Great Glad we could help...

Comment: But once again, thank you so much for your help – and apologies for the change in direction!

Answer (score 0):

I use https://wordpress.org/plugins/backwpup/ to backup (Files and Database) everything. I upload it to the new host. I update the sql tables in phpMyAdmin.

**Then if I want to keep the same domain name** then I just point the dns or change the a records.

**IF I want a new domain.** I use https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ to search and replace with OR without regex if you want (You can use for more than just domain name without knowing any SQL for phpMyAdmin.) and replace the **Old** domain name with the **NEW** domain name.